# what is the third term of the $\omega^{\omega}$-accelerated squares?

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinals

let $\{s_n\}_{n=0,1,2...}$ be a strictly increasing sequence of positive integers, indexed by the finite ordinals. if $S$ denotes the space of all such sequences, let the *accelerator function*, $\alpha \in End(S)$, be defined by:
$$ \alpha(s)_k = s_{s_k}
$$
likewise define $\alpha^2$ by 
$$\alpha^2(s)_k = \alpha(\alpha(s))_k = s_{s_{s_k}}
$$ and similarly for higher powers.
using all of these, we may define $\alpha^{\omega}$, for the first limit ordinal $\omega$ by the rule:
$$\alpha^{\omega}(s)_k = \alpha^k(s)_k 
$$ and then for the first successor ordinal of $\omega$:
$$\alpha^{\omega+1}(s)_k = \alpha^{\omega}(s)_{\alpha^{\omega}(s)_k} 
$$and for the next limit ordinal:
$$\alpha^{2\omega}(s)_k = \alpha^{\omega+k}(s)_{\alpha^{\omega+k}(s)_k}
$$for the higher-order limit ordinal $\omega^2$ we define
$$\alpha^{\omega^2}(s)_k = \alpha^{k\omega+k}(s)_{\alpha^{k\omega+k}(s)_k}
$$and for the higher ordinal $\omega^{\omega}$ we write:
$$\alpha^{\omega^{\omega}}(s)_k = \alpha^{k\omega^k +k\omega+k}(s)_{\alpha^{k\omega^k +k\omega+k}(s)_k}
$$
all these sequences are subsequences of the original sequence s.

QUESTION if we begin with the sequence of squares, i.e. $s_k=k^2$ ($k=0,1,2,...$) so that we have
$$\alpha^{\omega^{\omega}}(s)_0 =0 \\
\alpha^{\omega^{\omega}}(s)_1 =1
$$

what is the value of 
$$
\alpha^{\omega^{\omega}}(s)_2= ?
$$

Comment: Some arbitrary ordinals below $\omega^\omega$ such as $\omega^34+\omega+5$ seem to not be covered by this definition.